# Is it possible to run isort formatter from black command in python

Tags: python, python-poetry, python-black, isort

I like to get inspiration from well designed python projects.

The last one that inspired me was the [poetry repository](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry).

I copied a lot from that, but the subject of this post are [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [isort](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/).

Both are well configured in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
...
known_first_party = "poetry"


[tool.black]
line-length = 88
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
...
)/
'''
```

and formatting is configured in the `Makefile`as:

```
format: clean
    @poetry run black poetry/ tests/
```

I thought that running `make format` would run `black`which would internally run `isort`, but when I ran `isort .`, it correctly formated the import statements afterwards. It then seems `black` did not run `isort`.

Question: **does `black` run `isort` internally?**

Comment: Ok, then how does `poetry` run `isort` on formatting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question: does black run isort internally?

No, it doesn't.

`isort` has [a `profile = "black"`](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/profiles.html) option that makes it adhere to Black's standards though.

The `poetry` repository itself has a [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) hook [defined here in .pre-commit-config.yaml](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/b753aaf4c3c08ef0e54941a6616fe318fdf4f6e4/.pre-commit-config.yaml#L12-L17) that makes sure isort is run (along with a couple of other tools).

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't run isort.

As noted in this document, [*Using Black with other tools*](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/6559bdbd9dcf71ba0017d66bb133c744bd83b0e3/docs/guides/using_black_with_other_tools.md):

> #### isort
>
> isort helps to sort and format imports in your Python code. Black also
> formats imports, but in a different way from isort's defaults which
> leads to conflicting changes.